# Meteor: what is the final Location/URL after following redirects?

Tags: javascript, meteor, http-redirect

Meteor's [HTTP package](http://docs.meteor.com/#http_call) is a wrapper around mikeal's request, and it supports the `followRedirects` option. But how can one find out what the final URL is, after the 3xx redirect responses have been followed (and the request didn't [fail because of lack of a cookie jar](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/HdJK0n-09DA))?

With request, the final URL is in `response.request.href`. But with Meteor... ?

Here's the Meteor code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var url = 'http://google.com';
    var result = HTTP.call("HEAD", url, {
      followRedirects: true
    });
    console.log(result);  // nothing here hints at the final URL
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've created a package that does this - [http-more](https://atmospherejs.com/dandv/http-more).

Turns out Meteor doesn't pass back the request object within the response, and given the [history of rejected PRs concerning enhancements to the HTTP package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1703), I've just implemented that option separately.

Comment: Seems that the link of your package should be: https://github.com/StockBase/meteor-http-more

Comment: @JulienLeCoupanec: the correct GitHub link is https://github.com/dandv/meteor-http-more